# Issue with conntrack tool update mode - "conntrack -U -p tcp -t xx" does not work for specific states

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, iptables, netfilter

I face an issue Issue with conntrack tool update mode.
 "conntrack -U -p tcp -t xx" cmd does not works for specific TCP states.
I could not update timeout values for specific TCP states like Established, Time-wait, Syn-rcv state etc.

**Cmd1:**

conntrack -U -p tcp -t 80  ----> updates TO value for all TCP connection state.

```
Logs:

#conntrack -U -p tcp -t 80
#tcp      6 80 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.3.254 dst=192.168.3.254
sport=42218 dport=23 packets=77 bytes=4077 src=192.168.3.254
dst=192.168.3.254 sport=23 dport=42218 packets=55 bytes=3076 [ASSURED]
mark=0 use=2
conntrack v1.0.0 (conntrack-tools): 1 flow entries have been updated.
```

**Cmd2:**

conntrack -U -p tcp -t 30 --state ESTABLISHED (or)
conntrack -U -p tcp --state ESTABLISHED -t 30  -----> updates TO value
and states for all TCP connections.

```
# conntrack -L
#tcp      6 117 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.3.254 dst=192.168.3.254
sport=36047 dport=23 packets=51 bytes=2705 src=192.168.3.254
dst=192.168.3.254 sport=23 dport=36047 packets=36 bytes=2035 [ASSURED]
mark=0 use=2

#conntrack -U -p tcp -t 30 --state ESTABLISHED
#tcp      6 30 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.3.254 dst=192.168.3.254
sport=59521 dport=23 packets=82 bytes=4339 src=192.168.3.254
dst=192.168.3.254 sport=23 dport=59521 packets=57 bytes=3181 [ASSURED]
mark=0 use=2
conntrack v1.0.0 (conntrack-tools): 1 flow entries have been updated.
```

Do we have any method to update TO values only for established state
TCP connections? Can we set any target state flag for TCP proto for TO change by cmd options?

```
Packages used:
conntrack-tools-1.0.0
libnetfilter_conntrack-0.9.1
libnfnetlink-1.0.0
iptables-1.4.16
Linux kernel 2.6.34.8
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Murugan